# correct syntax for using Dispatcher to switch to UI thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

What is the difference between

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(somemethod);
```

and

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(somemethod);
```

When I use the first one the execution of somemethod is way faster than the second one.I used stopwatch and measured elapsed milliseconds.I use this method to update some UI controls based on some data coming from external thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` will get you **dispatcher associated with current thread** on which you are invoking this method.

Whereas `Application.Current.Dispatcher` will get **you dispatcher associated with UI thread** (assuming you App is launched from UI thread).

---

In essence if you are invoking delegate from background thread and try to update UI component from it say

```
textBlock.Text = "Test";
```

**First approach will fail** because it will invoke delegate on background thread dispatcher and UI components can only be modified from UI thread.

**Second approach will work** because it will delegate task on UI thread.

---

> When I use the first one the execution of somemethod is way faster
>   than the second one.I used stopwatch and measured elapsed
>   milliseconds.I use this method to update some UI controls based on
>   some data coming from external thread.

*If first approach worked for you* then there is **no need to use Dispatcher at all because that means you are already on UI thread**.

And you need to post sample data for your observation of timings so it can be validated.

Comment: Hey Rohit,Thanks for the crisp explanation.You are right, first approach should fail and I checked in my case it was working because I was updating a UI component binded to a Thread safe observable  collection:-) in  view model.I figured it out that other binded UI components are not refreshing with latest data.So some less UI refresh job was making the execution time lesser for first case.Anyways I am on right track now,thanks for help.